# Generate QR Code with Colors in every pixel of image and binary value

Tags: android, colors, qr-code

Well, I am doing a project with the QR Code. The idea of my project is to combine the numbers of QR Code(8-numbers of QR Code for my project) and generate a single color QR Code which idea is to increase the data storage of the QR Code.

However, so far I have done most of the part but I left the most important part which is generating color QR Code. The color QR Code has to be generated with the hexadecimal color and set the color to every pixel of the QR Code so it would be like a color QR Code. For now, I would try to generate with the Red color 1st.

So I have store the `binary` value in an `ArrayList` and the data is some sort like `10101010`. Then I change it to hexadecimal. Here is my code:

```
 ArrayList<String>arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 arrayList.add(a1+a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8); // Store 1110001 into ArrayList
 String [] hexArray = new String[arrayList.size()];
                    arrayList.toArray(hexArray);


 for(int a = 0; a < hexArray.length; a++){
     int dec = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(a)),2);
     String hexString = Integer.toString(dec, 16);
     String alpha = "0xff";
     String behind = "0000";
     hexArray[a] = alpha+hexString+behind;
 }
```

I have written some code of changing the color, but the code is changing the whole color of the QR Code which is the foreground and the background of QR Code as well.

```
 private Bitmap encode(String contents, int width, int height, @ColorInt int foreground, @ColorInt int background) {

    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix matrix = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        matrix = writer.encode(contents, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(matrix != null) {
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = matrix.get(x, y) ? foreground : background;
            }
        }
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Since ARGB having Alpha, Red, Green, Blue colors. **So what if I want to set the hexadecimal value just to Red color only. Then set to every pixel of the QR Code which will become a red color (would slightly different in kind of red color because the hexadecimal value is different) QR Code.**

Comment: `I need the solution` isn't the right way to ask for help. Also there is at least enough information in the linked question to make an attempt at say overlaying the two different QR codes into one with three colors: data 1 color, data 2 color, and say black for overlapping pixels. You would have to modify the QR reader to un-layer the  images but I think that is what you are trying to do. Regardless, update your question with attempt or more details about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Color.parseColor(hexadecimal)` to generate the color. The `hexadecimal` should be like `#ff00ff` RGB format or `#ff00ff00` ARGB format.

```
 for(int a = 0; a < hexArrayRed.length; a++){
   int dec = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(a)),2);
   String hexString = Integer.toString(dec, 16);
   while(hexString.length() < 2){
        hexString = "0"+hexString;
   }
   String head = "#ff";
   String behind = "0000";
   hexArrayRed[a] = head+hexString+behind;
   /*
             Red Hexadecimal Value --> #ff _ _ 0000
   */
 }
```

For your information, I add `while` statement to ensure the length of `hexString`. If the  binary is `00000011` and it is 3 in `hexadecimal` instead of 03. So I add "0" to the `hexString`.